# How to Stream MJPEG from Pi camera?

Tags: pi-3, camera, opencv

I want to make something like Surveillance system from pi camera. How can I do that with Opencv and pi camera ?
Can anyone please help me to understand How can I do like this [example](http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface). I am not a pi programmer but I want to learn as a hobbyist. Please explain that [example](http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface) for me so I can understand how they did. And I can start my one.

Thanks !

PS. I know this question may be broad. Please don't FLAG this question. I want to learn but I am not understanding the concept. If you are a good programmer, Please help me to understand.